# How to achieve digital zooming on javascript or node Js or reactJs environment

Tags: reactjs, node.js, image-processing, leaflet

**What am I trying to achieve?**

I have image of map which is tiff image width and height is 1024x1024 px and it will over lap on our map application (React,React_leaflet) at certain zoom level (e.g.18) the image started to blur here i need to incorporate digital zoom can this possible in javascript [This the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99Ihd.jpg)

I don't have any idea of where to start after Googling found some npm package like [sharp](https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/)   which is image processing but I don't think I can achieve digital zooming in this npm package

If anyone has implemented digital zoom in web application or in any software application please share code snippet or any documentation which helps to achieve digital zooming.

Thanks in advance any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you are trying to build a map like functionality, then you must know that map is built out of tiles. Each tile fetches an image. After a certain zoom the image is refetched most tilmes with more detailed imagery.

Comment: **Typo alert**: it's **achieve** - not "achive" ...

Comment: What do you mean with "digital zoom" here?

Comment: See the `zoomSnap` option for a Leaflet map.

Comment: @JJY9 ,I have map container and i do know about tiles and how it works, my concern is about the image that overlies on map container, so catch here is the tiff image overlies on my  map container application after 19+ zoom lever that overlay tiff image will be blur i need to come up with digital zoom like after 19+ zoom overlay image should not be blur i know we can,t increase pixel out of the air but some how it should not be pixelated image

Comment: hi@AKX, i have a use case where user will be on 20+ zoom level in my application the above image which i have shared in the question (goggle map image) is a tiff image will overlay on my applications map container so when you zoom above 20+ on this overlay image it will get pixelated so some how i need to keep the image quality good

Answer (score 0):

## HTML

```
<div id="zoom-container">
  <img id="zoom-image" src="image.jpg" alt="Zoomable Image">
</div>
<div id="zoom-controls">
  <button id="zoom-in">Zoom In</button>
  <button id="zoom-out">Zoom Out</button>
</div>


# CSS #

#zoom-container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

#zoom-image {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  transition: transform 0.2s ease-in-out;
}



# Javascript #

const zoomImage = document.getElementById("zoom-image");
const zoomInButton = document.getElementById("zoom-in");
const zoomOutButton = document.getElementById("zoom-out");

let scale = 1; // Initial scale factor

zoomInButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  scale += 0.1; // Increase the scale factor by 10%
  zoomImage.style.transform = `scale(${scale})`;
});

zoomOutButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  scale -= 0.1; // Decrease the scale factor by 10%
  zoomImage.style.transform = `scale(${scale})`;
});


// Limit the zoom level
const MIN_SCALE = 1;
const MAX_SCALE = 2;

zoomInButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (scale < MAX_SCALE) {
    scale += 0.1;
    zoomImage.style.transform = `scale(${scale})`;
  }
});

zoomOutButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (scale > MIN_SCALE) {
    scale -= 0.1;
    zoomImage.style.transform = `scale(${scale})`;
  }
});
```

Now, when you load this HTML and interact with the "Zoom In" and "Zoom Out" buttons, the image within the container will scale accordingly, providing a digital zoom effect. You can further customize the behavior, styles, and zoom limits to suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks for you answer,this answer was not helpfull sadly ,i want to improve the image quality by having digital zooming